# map structured data classes in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to map a structured data class in C# to a table in NHibernate

```
namespace X
{
    [DataContract]
    class StructureID
    {
        [DataMember] public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    class StructureNR
    {
        [DataMember] public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Y
{
    [DataContract]
    class SubStructure
    {
        [DataMember] public string SomeData { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string MoreData { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    class Structure
    {
        [DataMember] public StructureID StructureID { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public SubStructure SubData { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string OtherData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The table would contain colums like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Structures (
    ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    SOME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    MORE varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    OTHER varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The StructureID and StructureNR classes are semantic wrappers to let the compiler separate different meanings of "string", and SubStructure groups several members together. How would I map the Structure class to my table for read and write (we used XML definitions up to now)?

Comment: Please add the mapping that you did so far, and we will try to fix it.

Comment: What  we had until now is "flat" intermediate data classes, and AutoMapper calls for conversions. Also, because the flat classes might hold columns not present in the structured classes, this incurs an additional read before writing to the database. Currently we try to reduce the count of layers in our software to minimize total complexity, one of these layers is the intermediate flat data classes.

Comment: Why do you need StructureID in Structure? It makes the entity ID handling more complicated. Also, if you want SubStructure inside Structure it also have to have an ID.

Comment: The problem with flat string IDs is that we would have some.fun(string string string...) cropping up. By packaging the string inside a class, the wrapper class carries the string value together with some meaning (=the type of the wrapper). The compiler will then see to it that some.fun(thisID thatID otherID someNR...) don't get mixed up, especially when parameters are added/changed/dropped.

Comment: The SubStructure is to group values, as well as repeat the group several times, eg. in a few places we have request/planned/billed informations, or several addresses. Why should these SubStructure have IDs - this would only lead to having several versions of the original ID, which one would be used to finally write the Structure back to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

your solution should look along these lines, you will need to make adjustments according to your code.

Create 2 entities for the IDs.
Afterwards, create the main entities with composite IDs and connect by one-to-one relation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

  <class name="StructureID" table="Structures"  >
    <id name="Value">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
  </class>

  <class name="StructureNR" table="Structures"  >
    <id name="Value">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>   </class>

  <class name="SubStructure" table="Structures" >
    <composite-id name="StructureID" class="StructureID">
      <key-property name="Value">
        <column name="ID"></column>
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="SomeData">
      <column name="Some"/>
    </property>
    <property name="MoreData">
      <column name="More"/>
    </property>
  </class>

  <class name="Structure" table="Structures"  >
    <composite-id name="StructureID" class="StructureID">
      <key-property name="Value">
        <column name="ID"></column>
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="OtherData">
      <column name="Other"/>
    </property>
    <property name="Description">
      <column name="Description"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="SubData" class="SubStructure"  />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, we'll try along your proposal.